# Связь один ко многим, передача данных с таблиц БД в DataGrid

Tags: c#, база-данных, winforms

Такая ситуация. Есть две связанные между собой таблицы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задача в два DataGrid'a вывести список логинов юзеров и текст сообщений  соответственно так, чтобы по нажатию на определенного юзера показывало все входящие и исходящие сообщения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сделал таким методом:

```
private void GetData()
        {
            try
            {
                var loadData = cs.LoadFile("DataConnection.xml");
                string connString = String.Format("User Id={0};Host={1};Database={2};PWD={3}", loadData.UserId, loadData.Host, loadData.Database, loadData.PWD);
                NpgsqlConnection connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connString);

                // Create a DataSet.
                DataSet data = new DataSet();
                data.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

                // Add data from the Customers table to the DataSet.
                NpgsqlDataAdapter usersDataAdapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter("select * from users", connection);                
                usersDataAdapter.Fill(data, "users");

                // Add data from the Orders table to the DataSet.
                NpgsqlDataAdapter postsDataAdapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter("select * from posts", connection);
                postsDataAdapter.Fill(data, "posts");

                // Establish a relationship between the two tables.
                DataRelation relation = new DataRelation("UsersPosts",
                    data.Tables["users"].Columns["ID"],
                    data.Tables["posts"].Columns["UsersIDRecipient"]);
                data.Relations.Add(relation);

                // Bind the master data connector to the Customers table.
                BindingSource usersBindingSource = new BindingSource();
                BindingSource postsBindingSource = new BindingSource();
                usersBindingSource.DataSource = data;
                usersBindingSource.DataMember = "users";

                postsBindingSource.DataSource = usersBindingSource;
                postsBindingSource.DataMember = "UsersPosts";


                usersDataGridView.DataSource = usersBindingSource;
                postsDataGridView.DataSource = postsBindingSource;

                usersDataGridView.Columns["ID"].Visible = false;
                usersDataGridView.Columns["Password"].Visible = false;
                postsDataGridView.Columns["ID"].Visible = false;
                postsDataGridView.Columns["UsersIDSender"].Visible = false;
                postsDataGridView.Columns["UsersIDRecipient"].Visible = false;
                postsDataGridView.Columns["Data"].Visible = false;
            }
            catch (SqlException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error!");
            }
        }
```

Но таким методом показываются только входящие сообщения, как сделать чтобы и входящие и исходящие показывались?

Спасибо за любую помощь

Comment: у вас в таблице я вижу только одно поле куда сохраняются данные Техт не понятно что туда пишется отправленное сообщение или входящие или то и другое ? если оправленные то вам надо связывать таблицы в запросе по ID получателя и отправителя

Comment: @OXYGEN сообщения и те и другие, с помощью айдишек получателя и отправителя текст формируется для одного пользователя как отправленное и в это же время для другого как входящее. Не совсем понял, как их одновременно связать по айди получателя и отправителя

Comment: У вас в коде описана только одна связь между таблицами, а по описанию должно быть две. Стоит начать именно с этого, а там может и само подхватится, если нет - будем смотреть дальше.

Comment: @rdorn проблему решил,переписав запрос. Спасибо)